# Possible to combine regex for last word & number?

Tags: php, regex

I have a sample string such as

```
September 14-20, 26, 28-30, October 1-8, 10, 11, 15-20, 24, November 25, 28-30
```

When using `(\w+)$`, it will capture `30`. Is it possible to capture both `November` AND `30` using a single expression?

Comment: Do you want to capture _all_ months or only the last one?

Comment: `/([a-z]+)[^a-z]+?(\d+)$/i`  [Sandbox](https://regex101.com/r/y9HiB9/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `preg_match` here:

```
$input = "September 14-20, 26, 28-30, October 1-8, 10, 11, 15-20, 24, November 25, 28-30";
preg_match('/.*\b([A-Za-z]+).*\b(\d+)$/', $input, $matches);
echo "month is: " . $matches[1] . "\n";
echo "last day is: " . $matches[2];
```

This prints:

```
month is: November
last day is: 30
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking the format of your example string into account, you might make use of repeating groups and use 2 capturing groups where the first contains the name of the month and the second the last occurrence of 1 or more digits

```
^(?:[A-Za-z]+ \d+(?:-\d+)?(?:, \d+(?:-\d+)?)*, )*([A-Za-z]+)(?: \d+(?:-\d+)?,)* (?:\d+-)?(\d+)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[A-Za-z]+ \d+` match 1+ a-zA-Z, space and 1+ digits
  - `(?:-\d+)?` Optionally match hyphen and 1+ digits
  - `(?:, \d+(?:-\d+)?)*,`  Repeat 0+ times matching a comma, 1+ digits and optionally a hypen and 1+ digits
- `)*` Close non capturing group, repeat 0+ times
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[A-Za-z]+)(?: \d+(?:-\d+)?,`
- `)*`  Close group 1, repeat 0+ times and match a space
- `(?:\d+-)?` Match optional 1+ digits and hyphen
- `(\d+)` Capture group 2, match 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bK3y78/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
([A-Za-z]+)[\d, -]+?(\d+)$
```

[image]

[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/IcIqfm/1/)

---

In response to [`@lufac`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57282285/possible-to-combine-regex-for-last-word-number#comment101060635_57282378) comment

```
([A-Za-z]+)[^-]+-(\d+)$
```

[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/IcIqfm/2/)

---

If `-` before last number is also not always there you can use

```
([A-Za-z]+)[^a-zA-z]+?(\d+)$
```

[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/IcIqfm/3/)

Comment: This is correct for the example string given, but will only search for numbers, commas, spaces and dashes after the word. If there is any other character like an underscore, a slash or an apostrophe then it won't work (which may not be important if only dealing with month names and date ranges)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more verbose regular expression. It is a bit more targeted as well which let's you easily modify it if need more information later:

```php
$input = 'September 14-20, 26, 28-30, October 1-8, 10, 11, 15-20, 24, November 25, 28-30';
$num_matches = preg_match_all('~(?P<schedule>(?P<month>[A-Za-z]+?) (((\d{1,2}-)?(?P<endDate>\d{1,2}))(?:, )?)+)~', $input, $matches);
var_dump(
    array_pop($matches['schedule']),
    array_pop($matches['month']),
    array_pop($matches['endDate'])
);
```

It is making use of named groups which makes it super easy to extract the data you want from the `$matches`.

Since you just want the last month and its end date you simply pop the last value of each of those named groups.

And you'll get:

```
string(18) "November 25, 28-30"
string(8) "November"
string(2) "30"
```

[Demo link](https://regex101.com/r/5bMQBH/1/)

Answer (score 1):

A different method, not better or worse (in my opinion) is to split the string to parts and then pick what you need.
This had the benefit of having it all in arrays and therefore you can pick other months and dates quite easily.

```
$str = 'September 14-20, 26, 28-30, October 1-8, 10, 11, 15-20, 24, November 25, 28-30';

//Explode on [' ', ',', ', ', '-']    
$arr = explode(" ", str_replace(['-', ', '], ' ', $str));
$months = preg_grep("/\D+/", $arr); // find the months

$LastMonth = end($months);
$LastDay = end($arr);
var_dump($LastMonth, $LastDay); //November, 30
```

https://3v4l.org/GiqtI

---

This can also be written in such a way that you can recreate the full month strings or pick the last days in a range (28-30) using substr and strpos or post what was the last month like this:
https://3v4l.org/PBAXU

Answer (score 0):

`([a-zA-Z]+)[^a-zA-Z]+?([\d]+)$`

Word, not-a-word, number.

https://regex101.com/r/nFIc9H/1